# Write farsi in CLIPS(expert system)

Tags: clips, expert-system

I try to implementation a Expert System with Clips but clips doesn't support Farsi.
How do I write Persian in CLIPS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLIPS 6.3 internally supports UTF-8 strings, however, the application embedding CLIPS must also support UTF-8 I/O. The CLIPS Windows IDE does not support UTF-8 I/O. It uses older Win32 APIs and was not designed with unicode support in mind. The Mac OS X IDE, however, does support UTF-8 I/O:

```
CLIPS> 
(defrule hello
   =>
   (printout t "Hello" crlf)
   (printout t "Olá" crlf)
   (printout t "Здравствуйте" crlf)
   (printout t "مرح" crlf)
   (printout t "你好" crlf)
   (printout t "Γεια σας" crlf)
   (printout t "こんにちは" crlf)
   (printout t "안녕하십니까" crlf))
CLIPS> (run)
Hello
Olá
Здравствуйте
مرح
你好
Γεια σας
こんにちは
안녕하십니까
CLIPS> (read)
سلام
سلام
CLIPS>
```

When compiled as a console application, UTF-8 support for console I/O is environment dependent. A console version of CLIPS compiled with Darwin on Mac OS X supports UTF-8 automatically for console I/O. Apparently there is also some support in the Windows Command Prompt for UTF-8 console I/O if it is configured properly: [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500).

CLIPSJNI, http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/CLIPSJNIBeta.html, also demonstrates how you can embed CLIPS in an environment supporting UTF-8 (in this case Java) to take advantage of CLIPS internal support of UTF-8.